# Prevent a user from using Emoji smiles in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How to prevent the user from using this :

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your issue .....

Comment: update the issue with photo .. sorry if it is too big

Comment: Why cant you simply disable the keyboard or try its userinteraction=NO ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the UISearchBar delegate method:

- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text

When the user enters text the new characters appear in the "text" variable. If there is a selection the range has a length, otherwise its 0. Delete is a selection but 0 length text.

To prevent some characters from getting processed, you would return NO from this delegate method. If you want to get fancy, you could grab the current text (searchBar.text), change it to "DO NOT USE EMOJII!", then use dispatch_after() to then reset the text to its old value after 1 second or so.

Obviously you will need to figure out the unicode range of Emojii and/or anything else you want to block.

EDIT: So I did more researching on Emojii and this is what happens in the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    for(int i=0; i<[text length]; ++i) {
        NSLog(@"UNICHAR = %x", [text characterAtIndex:i]);
    }
    unichar c = [text length] == 1 ? [text characterAtIndex:0] : (unichar)'?';
    NSLog(@"Text: %@ unichar=%C (hex=%x)", text, c, c);

    return YES;
}
```

And tapping Emojii characters gets you this output:

```
2012-08-05 10:09:21.121 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = d83d
2012-08-05 10:09:21.130 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = de28
2012-08-05 10:09:21.135 Searcher[563:707] Text:  unichar=? (hex=3f)
2012-08-05 10:09:22.031 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = d83d
2012-08-05 10:09:22.035 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = de28
2012-08-05 10:09:22.040 Searcher[563:707] Text:  unichar=? (hex=3f)
2012-08-05 10:09:22.703 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = d83d
2012-08-05 10:09:22.709 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = de28
2012-08-05 10:09:22.715 Searcher[563:707] Text:  unichar=? (hex=3f)
2012-08-05 10:09:31.964 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = d83d
2012-08-05 10:09:31.969 Searcher[563:707] UNICHAR = de22
2012-08-05 10:09:31.973 Searcher[563:707] Text:  unichar=? (hex=3f)
```

So obviously when you use the Emojii keyboard you get text of length two with the above hex values. Emojii occupies a range of Unicode and you will find much if you google.

Comment: can you please complete building the searchBar function ? it seem little bit difficult

Comment: You need to adopt the UISearchBarDelegate protocol in your controller app and set the delegate of the searchbar to your class. Add the above method (which you can find by searching for UISearhBarDelegate in Xcode doc window. In that method add some log messages - log the search bar.text, the "text" object, and use NSStringFromNSRange() to print out the range. Experiment and you will see exactly how its working. Since you will have to support this and understand it, you should write it. It won't take you more than 1/2 hour to "get it". Always return YES to start.

Comment: sorry , but after 9 hours I failed ! 
can you help me please ? I am not professional yet ..

Comment: So, you have a UISearchBar object in your view, and you made yourself the delegate of that object, and you added the delegate object I told you about, and its never called as you type? Really, if I have to I will spin a quick app tomorrow on this - but if you cannot get this to work how will you ever get an app in the store?

Comment: Sorry - I am not trying to make things worse - you have this searchbard, can you get the delegate messages. That should be a first priority. If you can get them then your task will be easier. I will help you get this done.

Comment: thank you for helping .. to be honest No I do not Understand you, but I did drag search bar to .XIB and type : <UISearchBarDelegate>

Comment: So I created a project and you can get it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60414145/Searcher.zip Note that the delegate is set in the XIB. See how that delegate call is active when you enter text.

Comment: when I press delete button in simulator it gives me c07] Text:  unichar=? (hex=3f also there is many Emoji char not consider as ? like ☺

Comment: So how do I get Emoji in the simulator?